# Arch Linux 6.7.2-arch1-1 sporadically crashes / reboots

Tags: arch-linux, ssd, crash

I have recently built a new PC rig. At first everything seemed to work fine, but after a while, the system started crashing seemingly randomly.

"Randomly" meaning that it sometimes happens when I'm AFK, and sometimes when I'm working on my computer, without clear reproducible action. Also, "crash" meaning no error messages whatsoever; computer just shuts down *instantly* (all lights & monitors off in the blink of an eye), about 1 second delay, then reboot.

System specs:

```
MB: ASUS TUF GAMING B650-PLUS
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 7800X3D
GPU: AMD Radeon 7800 XT
PSU: Corsair RM850x
+ 2x Samsung 980 NVMe M.2 SSD, 1 TB
```

The command `last -x | head | tac` outputs:

```
reboot   system boot  6.7.2-arch1-1    Wed Jan 31 16:22 - 19:08  (02:46)
josh     tty1                          Wed Jan 31 16:22 - down   (02:45)
josh     pts/0        :1               Wed Jan 31 16:23 - down   (02:45)
shutdown system down  6.7.2-arch1-1    Wed Jan 31 19:08 - 21:49  (02:41)
reboot   system boot  6.7.2-arch1-1    Wed Jan 31 21:49   still running
josh     tty1                          Wed Jan 31 21:49 - crash  (01:13)
josh     pts/0        :1               Wed Jan 31 21:49 - crash  (01:13)
reboot   system boot  6.7.2-arch1-1    Wed Jan 31 23:03   still running
josh     tty1                          Wed Jan 31 23:08   still logged in
josh     pts/0        :1               Wed Jan 31 23:08   still logged in
```

The last few entries of `journalctl -b -1 -e` show:

```
Jan 31 22:50:39 binatz wpa_supplicant[612]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 0c:72:74:d1:49:11 [GTK=CCMP]
Jan 31 22:50:48 binatz env[3635]: [mp3float @ 0x71d8043d8200] Header missing
Jan 31 22:55:00 binatz env[3635]: [mp3float @ 0x71d804dad8c0] Header missing
Jan 31 22:56:03 binatz env[2498]: mainScreen.UpdaterEvents: CHECK_FOR_UPDATES UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE
Jan 31 22:56:03 binatz env[2498]: [OpenAsar > Modules] Checking
Jan 31 23:00:39 binatz wpa_supplicant[612]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 0c:72:74:d1:49:11 [GTK=CCMP]
Jan 31 23:02:29 binatz kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4079.0009: Disconnected
Jan 31 23:02:29 binatz kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4079.0009: Disconnected
```

I can't see anything off here, so I'm wondering if any of you has pointers where to look for crash reasons. Also, **important info**: I think these crashes started somewhen after I installed the second 1 TB NVMEe .M2 drive. Could the reason for the crashes be a faulty drive? If so, is there a way to know for sure?

I'd appreciate any help or tips, thanks!

EDIT: I ran `smartctl` on both drives. I'm not super familiar with the output parameters, but except for one drive having substantially more wear than the other, I can't see much wrong with them.

[image]

EDIT2: I don't know why I didn't mention this initially, but I'm dual-booting the system with Windows 11 and the issue does NOT occur when I boot Windows 11, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Linux having some issue with my setup.

Comment: If you take the drive out that you installed, does the issue disappear? Aside from that, remove the RAM, insert one stick only in Bank 0, and test for stability again.  If the problem continues, swap RAM sticks and then RAM slots.

Comment: Overclocked ? overheating ? inappropriate firmware settings ? loose connexions ?

Comment: After trying the above suggestions, I would also try the LTS kernel (if your hardware is supported by it, of course).

Comment: @MC68020 No components overclocked, thermals normal. Will try the other tips though.

Comment: could you try the zen kernel to see if that works?

Comment: So I have tried memory testing, updating the SSD firmware using Samsung Magician (it was heavily outdated), and using the zen kernel, all of which unfortunately did not solve the issue.